# svn commit showing updated files as added

Tags: svn, repository, checkin, svn-checkout

I checked in (modified )some of the files recently . When i'm trying to watch the Logs from my local machine every thing is perfect .(the checked in file shows modified status.)

But When i try to watch the Log History from someone else's machine ,the checked in files are showing as newly added .

Would someone suggest the reason for this strange behaviour .?

Comment: Which client are you and the other person using?

Comment: Please don't use question signatures to link to your blog. That's what your profile is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you `update`d the local working copy on the other machine? When viewing the history of a working copy, `svn log` shows the commits in the working copy, not the repository.

Answer (score 1):

Guess #1: Are you both working on the same code?  Verify that the checkout path is the same on both machines.

Answer (score 0):

It could be "new" to them (i.e. they had not checked out the files before you made your modifications).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are you checking into a different trunk, repository or branch.